# Using an OTG drive with Google Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music, usb-on-the-go

I just bought an OTG drive thinking I could mount it and cache music on it on Google Play Music. I am using a 2014 Moto X, with 16GB internal storage.

It mounts just fine on the device, but Google Play Music doesn't "see" the USB drive--the option is grayed out in the settings under "Storage Location". I'm able to use the OTG drive through other apps.

Is there any way to get this to work? Would it be possible to create a symlink from the internal drive onto the external drive, and if so, where would I even create the symlink at?

Comment: I think Play Music depends only upon mediaserver and doesn't do its own scanning. That would explain why it can't see USBOTG. Try binding the /mnt/usbotg to some folder in internal SD card and re-run mediaserver. Perhaps that may work. E.g., `su -c busybox mount --bind /mnt/usbotg/ /sdcard/SOME_DIR/`

Comment: Also, what about `su ln -s /mnt/usbotg /sdcard/SOME_DIR/`, which is what the OP wants, a folder symlink.

Comment: Also, re-running mediaserver is equivalent to rebooting your device

Comment: In case this works out, we can make it an answer

Comment: My situation appears to be different. I updated my Play Music and Play Services to latest, plugged USB drive and in Play Music's settings I didn't find any entry concerning OTG. However, after few seconds, in All songs, I was able to see all the songs available under USB drive  and I was able to successfully play them. So, is the app and Play Service updated?