# Music Player won't detect music on USB. Galaxy S7

Tags: 7.0-nougat, music-player, samsung-galaxy-s7

For some strange reason, my media player (I have tried MediaMonkey and Google Play Music) won't detect my music on my new USB. I can play music when I select the music file from the file explorer, but the music won't show up in either music player. I have checked to make sure there weren't any .nomedia files, and I selected the USB as the storage device in both MediaMonkey and Google Play Music. I refreshed and cleared caches, but none of these things help. And yes, the music files are supported by the players (I have both .mp3 and .flacs, niether show). Also, the files work fine on my PC, so I know they aren't corrupted or anything like that. I have also restarted my phone several times.
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S7
OS: Android 7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check here. The answer comments indicate that play music runs of media server. Which will scan your Internal storage and SD card but not your usb stick connected through the OTG. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/125290/145490

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just ended up buying Poweramp. It didn't have any issues reading the files off the USB. Sadly this cost me an extra 4$, but I was sick of trying to get Google Play to read the files properly.